# Создание пользователей Windows server 2019 (Скрипт)

Tags: powershell, скрипт

*Вот как то так он выглядит на PowerShell:*

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted #Разрешение неподписанных скриптов
Import-Module ActiveDirectory #Импорт модуля ADDS
$username=Read-host "Введите имя пользователя" # переменная для ввода имени пользователя
$password=Read-host "Введите пароль пользователя" #переменная для задания пароля
$count=01..30 #Кол-во пользователей
ForEach ($n in $count) #Обработка значений
{
    $pp = $n.ToString().PadRight("2","0")
    $pass = $pp + $password #Создание пароля
    $nn = $n.ToString().PadLeft("2","0")
    $un = $username + $nn #Создание логина
New-AdUser -Name $un -SamAccountName $un -GivenName $un -UserPrincipalName ($un + "@Kazan.wsr") -DisplayName $un -Path ***"OU=IT,DC=Kazan,DC=wsr"***-(вот тут менять подразделения) -PasswordNeverExpires $true -HomeDrive "G:" -HomeDirectory "\\srv1\shares\it\$nn" -CannotChangePassword $true -Enabled $true -ChangePasswordAtLogon $false -AccountPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString $pass -AsPlainText -force)
 #Сам скрипт создания
 Out-File "C:\USER_IT.txt" -Append -InputObject ($un + ";" + $pass) #сохранение пользователей в файл
}
```

Место выделенное тремя звездочками нужно сделать так чтобы нужно было вводить туда данные как сделано с username и password.

Comment: `$data=Read-host "вводить туда данные как сделано с username и password"` брать третью переменную и подставить ее в path
`...-Path "$data"...` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
New-AdUser -Path (read-host -prompt 'Enter subdivision to change')
```